# simplexml convertor always write java class name as xml root tag

Tags: java, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

I'm using Retrofit2 as REST client and SimpleXmlConverterFactory for converting from Java to xml, and from xml to Java object.

When I send response with NotificationResponse through REST, no one of the anotations seem to be applied.

```
@Root(name = "response")
public class NotificationResponse {
    @Element(name="message")
    private String msg;
    @Element(name="version")
    private String ver;
}
```

Instead of :

```
<response>
    <message>Hello</message>
    <version>1</version>
</response>
```

I'm sending:

```
<NotificationResponse>
<msg>Hello</msg>
<ver>1</ver>
</NotificationResponse>
```

Any idea, why @Root and @Element are ignored?

Comment: Are you sure that you've use right converter to serialize object?

Comment: I'm using:
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
      <artifactId>converter-simplexml</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I mean, how you initialize you converter? I suppose, you have somewhere a code line with "Retrofit.Builder()..."

Comment: return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(httpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

Comment: Strange. Then, I have no answers, but if SimpleXML is not strict dependency for your project, you can use Gson or JAXB, because SimpleXmlConverterFactory is deprecated in retrofit2 starting from version 2.4.0